# TPM showing error message

Tags: server, virtualbox, dmesg, virtualbox-networking, tpm

I have configured TPM for my virtual machine with Ubuntu 18.04.

`root@Virtual-Machine:~# dmesg | grep -i tpm`  ==> This should show a proper message

```
root@Virtual-Machine:~# journalctl  | grep tpm ==> shows error message
Virtual-Machine kernel: tpm_crb VTPM0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: Bad ACPI memory layout ==> This VM is reinstalled on oct 14 when the earlier edge stopped working.
Virtual-Machine kernel: tpm_crb VTPM0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: Bad ACPI memory layout
Virtual-Machine kernel: tpm_crb VTPM0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: Bad ACPI memory layout
Virtual-Machine kernel: tpm_crb VTPM0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: Bad ACPI memory layout
Virtual-Machine kernel: tpm_crb VTPM0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: Bad ACPI memory layout
Virtual-Machine kernel: tpm_crb VTPM0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: Bad ACPI memory layout
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need TPM settings in a VM?

Comment: From here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-provision-devices-at-scale-linux-tpm?view=iotedge-2020-11&tabs=physical-device%2Cubuntu you should understand that *"Autoprovision a Linux virtual machine (VM) with a simulated TPM running on a Windows development machine with Hyper-V enabled. **We recommend using this methodology only as a testing scenario. A simulated TPM doesn't offer the same security as a physical TPM."***